# Can't run Apache james on mac Sierra

Tags: java, macos, macos-sierra, java-home, james

I'm using Apache James as email server for development purpose on mac Sierra - v 10.12.3

When I try to start/run it as super user

```
sudo ./run.sh
```

it I get the following error:

```
ERROR: JAVA_HOME not found in your environment.

Please, set the JAVA_HOME variable in your environment to match the
location of the Java Virtual Machine you want to use.
```

When I try to run it without sudo, I get the following:

```
Using PHOENIX_HOME:   /Users/myUserName/Dev/james-2.3.2.1
Using PHOENIX_TMPDIR: /Users/myUserName/Dev/james-2.3.2.1/temp
Using JAVA_HOME:      /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_121.jdk/Contents/Home
Running Phoenix: 

Phoenix 4.2

James Mail Server 2.3.2.1
Remote Manager Service started plain:4555
org.apache.avalon.phoenix.containerkit.lifecycle.LifecycleException:    Component named "pop3server" failed to pass through the Starting stage. (Reason: java.net.BindException: Permission denied (Bind failed)).
at org.apache.avalon.phoenix.containerkit.lifecycle.LifecycleHelper.fail(LifecycleHelper.java:354)
```

The JAVA_HOME variable has been set correctly so far I know.

When I type $JAVA_HOME in terminal I get:

```
-bash: /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_121.jdk/Contents/Home: is a directory
```

in .profile and .bash_profile files I do have:

```
export JAVA_HOME=/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_121.jdk/Contents/Home
```

Any idea what could the reason be please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolved... the solution was to set the JAVA_HOME Environment Variable for Sudo. and this was done on: `/etc/sudoers`. I used 'vi' to edit the file via terminal.

```
sudo visudo
```

and then adding the following line after the Default settings for Environment Variables:

```
Defaults        env_keep += "JAVA_HOME"
```

That's all. To Check if the JAVA_HOME Environment Variable has been set correctly for sudo, I just typed this command in the terminal.

```
sudo printenv
```